# In the select startup item in VS, IIS Express option is absent instead "current document <documentname>" is present. Unable to build project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express

IISExpress option was present when I created .net core mvc web app. But on reopening the project, the startup item has "current document " option (along with 2 other individual files).

The application is entering break mode when selecting any of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the above problem by opening the .sln file inside my project directory for reopening my .net projects. It launches the project in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to choose Tools->Customize->Commands,and then click toolbar radio button,choose Standard.Then try to choose debug target,click `Delete` button and `Reset All` button.
[image]